# Vectorized boolean comparison: comparing 1 column to an entire matrix

Tags: numpy, scipy

I have a Scipy matrix

```
a = sps.csc_matrix( (z , (x,y)), shape = (N,N), dtype = int)
```

I have another 1D array `z` that I would like to compare to each column in `a` and count the matches.

```
count = 0
for i in range(N):
    count += (z == a[:,j]).sum()
```

This takes a VERY long time because the code is not vectorized. Is there a way to vectorize this comparison?

```
a == z
```

does not work. But I want something analogous to how `a*z` in numpy for two arrays will do a column-wise multiplication very fast, in contrast to explicitly looping over the columns of `a` and multiplying by `z`..

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example code that fully initializes the `a` and `z` matrices (i.e. define `z`, `x`, `y`, `N`).

Comment: @farenorth x, y, and z are just N-dimensional numpy arrays.

Comment: I don't think your loop does what you want it to. Take a look at `(z == a[:,i]).shape`. It's NxN!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this give you what you want?

```
(a == z[:, None]).sum()
```

Comment: `(a == z[:,None])` returns a single boolean. It is not even a vector. What does the 'None' do? I guess I could somehow replicate the columns of z into another matrix first and then do a matrix-matrix comparison...

Comment: Not for me; `(a == z[:, None])` gives a logical numpy array. It sounds like you may be redefining `a` in your code somewhere...

Comment: `z[:, None]` is a 'column-vector' *view* of `z`.

Comment: This works if I first convert my sparse matrix into a [dense] array, but not if I keep `a` as a sparse matrix.

Comment: I suspect this either a) has something to do with how you are constructing `a`, or b) this is a difference in our versions of numpy or scipy. [This](https://gist.github.com/lkilcher/e5e502af941bacd4dcfb) code works for me without converting a to a dense array.